# Source for a Generic PnP Monitor Driver

Tags: windows, drivers

I've been searching for the source for a Generic PnP Monitor Driver that's supposed to be available as a sample driver. I've looked in the WDK and the Windows 8/8.1 driver samples.

Does anyone know where I can find it?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/master/filesys/cdfs/pnp.c

Comment: Thanks - but it seems to be a CD File System driver.